# Intercept and divert graphic output before it hits the linux framebuffer, not using X11

Tags: linux, graphics, ffmpeg, video-streaming, framebuffer

I have been researching this issue for about a week, and it may be that I don't know the right questions to ask.

I am running a debian distro (Raspbian Stretch on the RaspberryPi). I am **not** using X11. Instead, I am booting straight to the command line, and will eventually probably boot straight up headless, starting a program at startup or sshing in to interact.

What I need to do is to start an application (a game engine specifically) that draws graphics to the framebuffer. Then, I need to **intercept** that stream **before** it makes it into the framebuffer, so I can work with it in real time.

Ultimately, I am using ffmpeg to compress and stream video of the output to another Pi. So, I want to be able to start an application and stream its output over a LAN, while still being able to interact with the command line in a separate thread.

I have the ffmpeg command to pull from `/dev/fb0`, and have successfully started the graphics application and streamed the content. But, is there anyway to intercept, capture, or redirect that application's output so it never actually hits the framebuffer? In my searching I have found many examples of writing to or reading from the framebuffer, but nothing about stopping content before it reaches the buffer.

I am happy with any solution that uses an existing package or application, or for C or RUST code that accomplishes what I need.

Thank you